# How to pronounce correctly final Y in words such as "city" or "story"?

Tags: phonetics, orthography

I am interested in pronunciation of the letter Y at the end of the words, such as *city, story, belly, penny* and so on. Wonder what sound it denotes. I understand it is some kind of [i] sound. But is it a tense or a lax vowel?

Comment: Is your question how it is pronounced or whether that is characterized as a "tense" or "lax" vowel (btw, I don't know what those terms mean)?

Comment: It is mainly about how it is pronounced. I consider to edit the title of my question so it will be easier to understand.

Comment: I'm confused about this question; specifically, I don't understand why you can't just open up an online dictionary entry, and click on the icon which plays an audio version of the word being pronounced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For most modern English speakers, it's a tense vowel /i/ and not a lax vowel /ɪ/. This is not universal: you hear /ɪ/ from some elderly upper-class speakers in Atlanta, for example. Nevertheless, I would recommend /i/ unconditionally to a learner in any English-speaking country.

This is a relatively recent development; see here for more information than you could ever need:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_high_front_vowels#Happy_tensing